# Small particles from broken iPhone charging cable

Tags: cables, iphone

While trying to fix an iPhone charging cable, I noticed I had some small particles on my fingers, that looked like metal. I wonder if any of the materials I touched and manipulated could have released some dangerous small particles, dust, or fibers; similar to (I read online) optical fiber cable releasing glass fiber particles when cut.

In the dark image, the small particles that look metallic can be seen on the table.

Can they be dangerous? What are they?

[image: Broken iPhone charging cable]

Answer (score 6):

Those look like pieces of shield braid; just little short sections of uninsulated wire. I suppose they could be a hazard if they got in your eye but no, they are not toxic or anything. The biggest problem is that they are conductive and can bridge small gaps, causing short circuits.

Answer (score 3):

It's shield braid, they create a wire mesh around the shield to block electric fields.

It's dangerous as far as you can prick your finger on it and bleed a little if you're not careful but that's about it.